# Simplex decision about row operation

Tags: linear-programming, simplex, gaussian-elimination

My question is very general, but i would be putting a very especific problem just to clarify and avoid doubts.

Suppose i'm using the simplex method to solve the following problem:

Maximize: $20 x_{1} + 10x_{2} + 15x_{3}$

subject to   $3x_{1} + 2x_{2} + 5x_{3} \leq 55$

$2x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} \leq 26$

$x_{1} + x_{2} + 3x_{3} \leq 30$

$5x_{1} + 2x_{2} + 4x_{3} \leq 57$

$x_{1} , x_{2}, x_{3} \geq 0$

Lets call $z$ to the objective function:
When i put the slack variables ($S_{i}$ for i =1,2,3,4)  and i write the tableau i get:

$\begin{matrix} z& x_{1}& x_{2}& x_{3}& S_{1}& S_{2}& S_{3}& S_{4}& RHS \\
1& -20& -10& -15& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0 \\
0& 3 & 2 & 5 & 1& 0& 0& 0& 55 \\
0& 2 & 1 & 1 & 0& 1& 0& 0& 26 \\
0& 1 & 1 & 3 & 0& 0& 1& 0& 30 \\ 
0& 5 & 2 & 4 & 0& 0& 0& 1& 57 \\  \end{matrix}$

I know that the first step is to change $x_{1}$ from beying a cero-variable in reeplacement of $S_{4}$, so basicly i want to convert the column:

$\begin{matrix} -20 \\
3\\
2\\
1\\
5\end{matrix}$

to:

$\begin{matrix} 0 \\
0\\
0\\
0\\
1\end{matrix}$

The question is:

If i'm allowed to use any elementary row operation, i can use for example the following:

Add $\frac{20}{3}$ times the second row to the first (to convert the $-20$ in $0$), and so on...

The point is that if i do this, the simplex method ends in the next step, because the first row in the tableau would be:

$\begin{matrix} 1 &0 &\frac{10}{3} &\frac{55}{3} &\frac{20}{3} &0 &0 &0 &\frac{1100}{3} \end{matrix}$

Because there isn't a negative value in the first row, the problem is finished. But this is not the solution of the problem. I know that the best decision is to use as a pivot the last row in:

$\begin{matrix} -20 \\
3\\
2\\
1\\
5\end{matrix}$

But why can i not use other rows? What am i missing?

Comment: This is due to feasibility constraint.  You have to ensure that every decision variables are nonnegative.

Comment: You want to keep the columns related to $S_1-S_3$ equal to unit vectors.